React - Axios not attaching session cookies in requests
i have this 2 endpoints in backend nestjs app:
@Post(authPaths.login)
@UseGuards(LocalGuard)
async login(@Req() req: Request, @Res() res: Response) {
  const user = req.user as User;
  const tokens = await this.authService.generateInitialTokens(user);

  // Set the cookies
  res.cookie('accessToken', tokens.accessToken, {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    sameSite: 'none',
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 15,
  });

  res.cookie('refreshToken', tokens.refreshToken, {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    sameSite: 'none',
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
  });

  return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Login successful' });
}

@Get(authPaths.status)
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
status(@Req() req: Request) {
  return req.user;
}

I am trying to access the status endpoint on my nextJS frontend app with this piece of code:
const api: AxiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:3210",
  withCredentials: true,
});

...

export const login = async (email: string, auth_identifier: string) => {
  const response = await api.post("/auth/login", { email, auth_identifier });
  return response.data;
};

export const status = async () => {
  const response = await api.get("/auth/status", {
    withCredentials: true,
  });
  return response.data;
};


When i call the login api from the frontend, i get status 200 and i can see that the cookies are created under inspect -> application -> storage -> localhost:
enter image description here
However, when i try to hit the status endpoint, i get 401 unauthorised. If i go to the network tab and select the status call, i cannot see the token cookies assigned anywhere in the request:
enter image description here
enter image description here
i tried doing curl request from the terminal passing the cookie manually to check if the backend acts correct:
curl -X GET http://localhost:3210/auth/status --cookie "accessToken=your-access-token; refreshToken=your-refresh-token"

When i do the request from terminal, i get response from the status api. I am authenticated.
I investigated axios further but still cannot make it include cookies in the requests.
Also tried setting axios defaults using:
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

But there is no result. Apart from this i also did several tests trying to manually set the cookie to see if this works:
const response = await api.get("/auth/status", {
  headers: {
    Cookie: "accessToken=123; refreshToken=2323"
  },
});

Any suggestions are welcome.
